# Register Module error in upgrading from angular 8 to angular 9

Tags: angular

I have upgraded angular 8 to angular 9 in a project and I am getting an error whenever I am trying to navigate to a different component. The error is :

```
core.js:6241 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:36282:1)
    at core.js:36300:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:36296:1)
    at core.js:36300:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:36296:1)
    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:36461:1)
    at Compiler_compileModuleSync__POST_R3__ (core.js:41101:1)
    at Compiler.Compiler_compileModuleAsync__POST_R3__ [as compileModuleAsync] (core.js:41114:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750:1)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41686:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569:1)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:484:1)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621:1)
```

I have added serviceWorker to imports and SwUpdate to providers in root module.
I have also tried out various fixes available on internet -

1. checking routes and configurations
2. Matching typescript compatibility.

But so far have been unable to identify neither the error nor the solution.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No it did not help me out